# "New-IshSession : One or more errors occurred" dont know why it is showing this error?

Tags: sdl-tridion, powershell, tridion-docs

```
Import-Module 'Posh-SSH'
$ishBaseUrl = "https://<link>"
$ishUsername = "<username>"
$ishPassword = "<password>"
$targetOutputName = "DocPortal"
echo "" ; "Job started: $(Get-Date)" ; ""
$ishSession = New-IshSession -WsBaseUrl $ishBaseUrl -IshUserName $ishUsername -IshPassword $ishPassword
```

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, Pavan. I'm afraid your question isn't very clear and so is currently hard to answer. I believe an actual error and ideally a stack trace would help greatly. Could you check the logs (event log and the logs on the service it is connecting to) and also repeat the command with the -Verbose parameter? Then add as much detail to your question as you can.

Comment: Sounds like this is a Tridion *docs* question rather Tridion *sites*. I'll ping some people at SDL.

Answer (score 2):

The question is regarding https://github.com/sdl/ISHRemote/ which is a business automation module on top of Tridion Docs. As of our combined Tridion DX messsage, we might see more Docs-oriented questions appear.

Regarding the error message "One or more errors occurred", this is the generic message you get when the code for some reason triggers a "System.AggregrateException".

Assuming you use the latest available version of ISHRemote, you could add -debug and -verbose to the New-IshSession call so we see more verbose logging.

Now in the meanwhile, you might have workaround your problem, happy to hear how you resolved this one.